# Setting a destination location in Uber Business account's updated Ride policy

Tags: uber-api

Currently, I can specify pickup locations in ride policy in Uber Business account. How can I set a destination location in ride policy in same account?

These policies were pretty simple earlier, but have been complicated now. Whenever, I choose a location mentioned in ride policy as destination while booking a ride, it gives me an error that this is not in accordance with ride policy, but the same location can be used as a pickup location to book ride.